# Вынести URLSession dataTask в свою очередь

Tags: swift

Заметил такую особенность - при использовании URLSession Data Task, данный метод сам уходит в Global queue. Но что если я хочу вынести это в собственную очередь, которую я создал? Чтобы `URLSession.dataTask` выполнялся в той очереди, в которой я захочу. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно только передав ему [delegatequeue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411571-delegatequeue) в [ините](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411597-init)

Пример кода на swift5.3:

```
 class Delegate: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {
        func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
            guard let queueLabel = OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue?.label else { return }
            print(queueLabel) 
     }
 }
    
func getData() {
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Queue")
    let delegate = Delegate()
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
    operationQueue.underlyingQueue = dispatchQueue
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://www.google.ru/")!)
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]